# Merge two array of objects

Tags: javascript, lodash

It's me, again :D 
I have some problem and can't solve it.

A have two arrays of objects. In both, there is missing information. And I want to merge them, but with some rules:

1. I have nested objects
2. Take value from the first object and to
   replace with it value in the second if the value is equal in the
   second to zero

First my array of objects

```
componentId:"ExchangeCurrency"
componentModel:"{"CurrencyRate":0.021362956633198035,"DebitAccount":null,"CreditAccount":null,"PurchaseAmount":"42.73","PaymentAmount":"2000","CommissionResult":{}}"
```

And second

```
componentId:"ExchangeCurrency"
componentModel:"{"CurrencyRate":0.0,"DebitAccount":{"AccountId":134118,"TypeId":64,"CardId":64531,"CurrencyId":22,"CardPaymentSystemTypeId":1523,"Label":"Зарплатная++","AvailableOwnFunds":111105.83,"Overdraft":500000.0,"IsPaymentFromCard":true,"ContractId":233,"AccountCloseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},"PurchaseAmount":0.0,"PaymentAmount":0.0,"CreditAccount":null,"CommissionResult":null,"PaymentReason":null}"
```

In the second object as you see keys of 'CurrencyRate', 'PurchaseAmount' and 'PaymentAmount' matter 0.0. And this is my target, to take `CurrencyRate` value from the first object and to insert it in `CurrencyRate` at the second object.

At the finish, I want to see array of object like this one

```
componentId:"ExchangeCurrency"
componentModel:"{`"CurrencyRate":0.021362956633198035`,"DebitAccount":{"AccountId":134118,"TypeId":64,"CardId":64531,"CurrencyId":22,"CardPaymentSystemTypeId":1523,"Label":"Зарплатная++","AvailableOwnFunds":111105.83,"Overdraft":500000.0,"IsPaymentFromCard":true,"ContractId":233,"AccountCloseDate":"0001-01-01T00:00:00"},`"PurchaseAmount":"42.73"`,`"PaymentAmount":"2000"`,"CreditAccount":null,"CommissionResult":null,"PaymentReason":null}"
```

I wrote some lines of code, but it doesn't work with nested objects [Check JsFiddle pls](https://jsfiddle.net/bz5Lswqs/39/)

Any help will be appreciated!

UPD:

Code from the project. P.S. Console.log for debugging

```
if (this.props.location.state.formData.componentValues) {
        const formData = [];
        this.props.location.state.formData.componentValues.forEach((item) => {
          const newItem = {};
          newItem[item.componentId] = JSON.parse(item.componentModel);
          formData.push(newItem);
        });
        const formatedFormData = formData.reduce((p, c) => Object.assign(p, c), {});
        console.log(this.toComponentValues(formatedFormData), 'formatedFormData');

        if (localStorage.accountData) {
          const { debitAccountId } = JSON.parse(localStorage.accountData);
          service.GetPrefilledWizardPage({
            type: { formType: paymentType, ...formTypeParam },
            debitAccountId,
          })
            .then((data) => {
              function customizer(objValue, srcValue) {
                console.log(objValue, srcValue, 'customizer');
                return !objValue ? srcValue : objValue;
              }

              const defaults = _.partialRight(_.assignWith, customizer);
              console.log(data.paymentRequestRequisiteForm.paymentRequestRequisiteModel.componentValues[0]);

              console.log(defaults({}, data.paymentRequestRequisiteForm.paymentRequestRequisiteModel.componentValues, this.toComponentValues(formatedFormData)));
            })
          localStorage.removeItem('accountData');
        }

        // this.loadPage({
        //   type: { formType: paymentType, ...formTypeParam },
        //   componentValues: here I want to pass my merged array of objects,
        // }, extraComponentConfig);
      }
```

UPD2: It's not work too :(  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sr3e9k5e/13/)

Comment: please add the code to the question.

Comment: From my project?

Comment: i mean the part where you try to merge the objects, please have a looke here, too: [mcve]

Comment: Ok, I just updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task is solved! I'm happy!
[Answer](https://jsfiddle.net/sr3e9k5e/72/)

```
Array({ ...input2[0],  componentModel: _.assignWith({}, input2[0].componentModel, input1[0].componentModel, (t, s) => t ? t : s)})
```